# What are the best ways to convert different parts of speech to noun?

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I am working on a topic modelling task. I want to convert different parts of speech such as adjectives, verbs to noun. What are the best ways of doing this? I have tried lemmatization using NLTK library but I see this does not work for most of the words.